# Issue with setting focus on to a SELECT between KeyDown and KeyUp events (Firefox bug?)

Tags: jquery, select, focus

When I handle the arrow keys (up/down/left/right) using the KeyDown event of an element to set focus onto a SELECT, the SELECT which gets "focused" seems the receive a "KeyUp" event which makes it select the next/previous OPTION (depending on which arrow you pressed).

It only happens in Firefox (tested in 3 & 4), where as IE8 & Chrome work as expected (they don't change the value of the "focused" SELECT).

The code below reproduces the issue (just press any arrow key and it will focus the other ):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>KeyUp Issue</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("select")
            .live("keydown", function(event)
            {
                switch (event.keyCode)
                {
                    case 37: // left
                    case 38: // up
                    case 39: // right
                    case 40: // down
                        $(this).siblings().focus();
                        event.preventDefault();
                        break;
                }
            })
            .live("keyup", function(event)
            {
                // This event handler makes absolutely no difference; it's still
                // "broken" in Firefox and works fine in IE/Chrome without it.
                switch (event.keyCode)
                {
                    case 37: // left
                    case 38: // up
                    case 39: // right
                    case 40: // down
                        event.preventDefault();
                        break;
                }
            })
            .live("keypress", function(event)
            {
                // This event handler makes absolutely no difference; it's still
                // "broken" in Firefox and works fine in IE/Chrome without it.
                switch (event.keyCode)
                {
                    case 37: // left
                    case 38: // up
                    case 39: // right
                    case 40: // down
                        event.preventDefault();
                        break;
                }
            });
    </script>
    <select id="select1">
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
        <option>Three</option>
        <option>Four</option>
    </select>
    <select id="select2">
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
        <option>Three</option>
        <option>Four</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keypress event is the one which would need to be canceled, but Firefox ignores preventDefault() in this scenario. So the solution is to blur the current dropdown, let the keypress event fire on the document and set the focus to the new dropdown via timeout.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/3vA53/

Comment: Thanks roberkules, that works brilliantly! And thanks for showing me jsfiddle.net too, awesome site!

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, jsfiddle seems great, also stumbled upon it on SO a few days ago. Another site where you think, why didn't I have the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is the key press right ?

http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-keyboard-events-example/

should help you understand why! Something to do with case sensitivity characters I think.

Comment: Btw Scroll down you have a demo at the bottom, should give u an idea as to why didnt your arrow buttons work

Comment: No, the KeyPress is not the issue (infact whether it is there or not make absolutely no difference whatsoever), the second SELECT does get focused, but then it's value changes, which it should not as I have called preventDefault() (infact without this call, in IE & Chrome the original SELECT's value gets changed which it what I would expect to happen).

Comment: Yeah, I tried `return false;` after the preventDefault, but that made no difference. I get the feeling it's just a bug in Firefox and I might just have to live with it :o(

Comment: I know (arrow) for sure it would not work on keypress, but there is no reason why it shudn't work on keyup,keydown